# Bin-smooth in R using glm

Tags: r, glm

I'm trying to implement a bin-smooth (I've also seen it called a step function or a regressogram) in R, using `glm`. It works perfectly as long as there aren't too many bins. I tried this first of all but I can't get predictions out of it for any more than about 15 bins:

```
binsmoothfit <- glm(mpg ~ cut(displacement, 20), data=auto)
predict(binsmoothfit, data.frame(displacement=min(displacement):max(displacement)))
#Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, 
#xlev =object$xlevels) :factor cut(displacement, 20) has new levels (203,223],    
#(281,300],(320,339]
```

I guess this is because some of the cuts given by the cut function are empty:

```
table(cut(displacement,20))
#(67.6,87]  (87,106] (106,126] (126,145] (145,165] (165,184] (184,203] (203,223]
# 30        77        58        31        22         9        13         0        
#(223,242] (242,262] (262,281] (281,300] (300,320] (320,339] (339,358] (358,378] 
# 32        25        3         0         42        0         27        4           
#(378,397] (397,417] (417,436] (436,455] 
# 3         13        3         6
```

So I tried using quantiles instead but that also does not work. Although I am less sure why as we do have some data points in each of the cuts:

```
binsmoothfit <- glm(mpg ~ cut(displacement, breaks=quantile(displacement, 
probs=seq(0,1,1.0/20))), data=auto)   
predict(binsmoothfit, data.frame(displacement=min(displacement):max(displacement)))
# Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = 
# object$xlevels) : factor cut(displacement, breaks = quantile(displacement, probs = 
#seq(0, 1, 1/20))) has new levels (68,87.3], (87.3,107], (107,126], (126,145], 
#(145,165], (165,184], (184,203], (203,223], (223,242], (242,262], (262,281], 
#(281,300], (300,320], (320,339], (339,358], (358,378], (378,397], (397,416], 
#(416,436], (436,455]

table(cut(displacement,breaks=quantile(displacement, probs=seq(0,1,1.0/20))))
#(68,85]   (85,90]   (90,97]   (97,98]  (98,104] (104,112] (112,120] (120,122]  
#25        18        34        19         3        23        24        18         
#(122,140] (140,148] (148,168] (168,200] (200,231] (231,250] (250,262] (262,305] 
# 27         7         22        19        21        28        10        19         
#(305,318] (318,350] (350,400] (400,455] 
# 24        19        28         9
```

Does anyone know what to do? Is there a nice way of merging together the intervals without any data points in them? Or is there another way of doing this? What does "factor has new levels" mean anyway? I'd really like to use `glm` because then I have automatic access to predictions, cross validation etc.

The data I am using is Auto MPG data set from the UCI Machine Learning repository:

```
auto <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data",
col.names = c("mpg", "cylinders", "displacement", "horsepower", "weight", 
"acceleration", "model_year", "origin", "car_name"))

attach(auto)
```

Comment: Your file link is "404 Not Found". Maybe you can replicate the problem using R's built-in `mpg` data set?

Comment: I've changed the link now. The new link should work.